# Contradiction and Tautology in Propositional Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

How can the following statements be true if they are put in a tautology formula like A -> (A or B)

A: James deleted the email.
B: James forwarded the email.

If these two propositions are substituted in the tautology given above, then how is it possible for the email to be deleted and forwarded? Isn't it a contradiction?

Comment: If James deleted the email, then James deleted *or* forwarded the email. It's not "and" as you thought.

Comment: Yes but if James deleted the email, then he will not be able to forward it. So, it should evaluate as false, isn't it? But it will be true no matter what because of the tautology. This is what is confusing me!

Comment: If James deleted the email, then he deleted or forwarded the email. What's true given the antecedent is that James deleted *or* forwarded the email. The tautology doesn't claim that given the antecedent, James forwarded the email ($B$).

Comment: If you have blond hair then the statement that you have blond hair or you have brown hair is true. That's the part you don't seem to understand. If James deleted the mail then "James deleted the mail or James forwarded the mail" is true because one of those is true. It is also true that "James deleted the mail or James printed then used the mail as a suppository". The disjunction is true as long as at least one of the statements is true.

Comment: Yes, but I am being asked to state "what is wrong" about placing these two statements in the given formula which is a tautology. My intuition, too, says that if James deletes the mail then he's not required to forward it, and if he forwards it, then he's not required to delete it because the tautology doesn't require that. The consequent causes it to be true regardless of what happens after forwarding or deletion.

Comment: I also wonder "what is wrong" and where the contradiction might be. What is "it" that the consequent ($A\text{ or }B$) causes to be true regardless of what happens after forwarding or deletion?

Comment: If it is true that the email was deleted, then statement A is true, which implies $A$ **or** $B$ is true. If $A$ is false(email was not deleted), then truthness of $A \lor B$ depends on $B$. But it doesn't anyways matter because the antecedent is false, so the implication is true.

Comment: See also the post [What exactly does tautology mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970851/what-exactly-does-tautology-mean): *tautology* and *contradiction* are concepts related to formulas of propositional logic and their interpretation.

Comment: "Isn't it a contradiction?" No, it is a tautology. "what is wrong?" Maybe the use of "inclusive disjunction": the real life case is more aptly modellrd with XOR (exclusive disjunction) because A and B cannot be both true.

Answer (score 1):

> How can the following statements be true if they are put in a tautology

They aren't. It is $A \to (A \lor B)$ that is true under any given interpretation, not $A$ or $B$ themselves.

Edit re. your comment:

> but if James deleted the email, then he will not be able to forward it.

Yes, but that doesn't matter. There is nothing that says that James did delete the e-mail, nor that he forwarded it. All that's being said is that if James deleted the e-mail, then he deleted it or he forwarded it.

Just because a propositional letter occurs as a part of a formula that is true under a given circumstance doesn't mean that part itself has to be true too.

Consider an even simpler example: $A \lor \neg A$. This formula is tautological as you can easily verify, but of course this doesn't mean that whatever proposition $A$ can stand for must be true in any given situation. Just $A \lor \neg A$ must be. Otherwise, every statement whatsoever would be tautological!

Comment: Yes but if James deleted the email, then he will not be able to forward it. So, shouldn't evaluate as false? But it has to be true because of the tautology and this part is causing confusion.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: I am being asked to state "what is wrong" about placing these two statements in the given formula which is a tautology. My intuition, too, says that if James deletes the mail then he's not required to forward it, and if he forwards it, then he's not required to delete it because the tautology doesn't require that. The consequent causes it to be true regardless of what happens after forwarding or deletion.

Comment: If that is indeed what's being asked, then it's a strange question. To begin with there is never anything wrong with putting statements in a formula. Whether it comes out as true or not in the real world is a different question. But here I don't even see any problem with the fact that the result is tautological. Can you please state explicitly what the question asks?

Comment: The exact question is reproduced below:

Suppose that we have a proposition A: "James deleted the email." and proposition B: "James forwarded the email."
Keeping these definitions of A and B in mind, what does the formula "a -> (a ∨ b)" imply when these propositions are substituted in it? In other words, write the formula "a -> (a ∨ b)" in terms of "James deleted the email" and "James forwarded the email."
What went wrong?

Comment: A hint was also supplied:

You will notice that the propositions "James forwarded the email" and "James deleted the email" don't fit nicely in the formula  "a -> (a ∨ b)". What causes this statement to fail after using the given two propositions?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the question getting at, but I don't see where you're getting the problematic assumptions from. The question doesn't claim or imply anywhere that A and B should both be true.